# Using Index/Max/If to find multiple values in array and get for highest corresponding value result displayed

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I am currently trying to use some excel formulas like "Index"/"Max"/"If" with multiple criteria. This means I want to lookup all values in A2:I2 and search them in my second table in A8:A20. At the same time I want to lookup the maximum in C8:C20 and for the entry that 
1) matches A2:A20 and 2) has the highest value in C2:C20 I want to get the value of the "Result" column be displayed in I7, which is "D".

[image]

After trying multiple variations with Index/Vlookup/Max/If etc. I cannot find any formula for this problem to handle multiple matching criteria within arrays.

Perhaps is there any VBA solution to loop through both tables and get the result displayed below?

P.S. As this is only a small part of my worksheet it is not efficient to use one Index formula for each cell trying to match my second table. It would be great to work with two arrays matching each others values.

Comment: Did you try coding with vba?

Comment: not yet. I want to give it a try with some casual formulas before writing some VBA code.

Answer (score 0):

Using your provided sample, in result cell I7 use this formula: `=MAX(INDEX((A8:A20=A2:I2)*C8:C20,))`

Comment: Sorry, I just recognized that I made a mistake in my example. The value that I want to get displayed is the one from the "result" column and not from the "value" column as this would be no big problem using a simple Max/Index formula as you suggested! I did edit my post!